# How to send test BTC from one address to another with c# NBitcoin?

Tags: c#, .net, bitcoin, nbitcoin

I am trying to figure this out for like three days now. I think my problem is not in transaction builder but in `.AddCoins` part.

```
TransactionBuilder builder = Network.TestNet.CreateTransactionBuilder();

var transaction = builder
                .AddCoins(coins)
                .AddKeys(myPrivateKey)
                .Send(addressThatIamSendingTo, Money.Coins(amountToSend))
                .SetChange(addressThatIamSendingFrom);
            
var fee = transaction.EstimateFees(new FeeRate(1m));
                
var finalTransaction = transaction.SendFees(fee).BuildTransaction(true);
```

My coins in `.AddCoins` are from here:

```
var balance = client.GetBalance(myBtcAddress); // client is from QBitNinjaClient client = new QBitNinjaClient(Network.TestNet);

var sum = 0m;
            
            
foreach (var operation in balance.Result.Operations)
{
    sum += operation.Amount.ToDecimal(MoneyUnit.BTC);
                
}
            
Console.WriteLine("Sum {0} is ", sum);
            
var amountToSend = 0.0002m;
var transaction = Network.TestNet.CreateTransaction();
transaction.Outputs.Add(new TxOut(Money.Coins(sum), myScriptPubKey));
            
Coin[] coins = transaction.Outputs.AsCoins().ToArray();
```

Thing is that `builder.Verify(finalTransaction)` says `True` but after broadcast with `QBitNinja` or `Local Node` that is configured to hit `TestNet` even, I got transaction id, i can not see it anywhere and BTC is not transferred.

Comment: var coins = client.GetBalance(myAddress, true).Result.Operations.SelectMany(op => op.ReceivedCoins).ToArray();

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out i was calling this freaking balance in wrong way.

`client.GetBalance(myAddress, true)`// where true is un spent coins ....

and then transaction coins are `.AddCoins(client.GetBalance(myAddress, true).Result.Operations.SelectMany(op => op.ReceivedCoins).ToArray())`